# Passing link-value from dropdown to another button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on an ordering system that allows the user to choose a specified vendor from a dropdown-menu and comfirm their selection by clicking a seperate button.

A perfect example would be the [Fallout 4 store page](https://www.fallout4.com/buy-now), where the "Order"-button is disabled until an item has actually been selected from the dropdown menu. (In my case there is only one dropdown menu).

I've got the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="productRow">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="dropdownPositionLeft">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Choose your platform!
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <!-- List of vendors -->
                    <li><a tabindex="-1">Item I</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1">Item II</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1">Item III</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="dropdownPositionRight">
                <!-- This is the button that confirms the selection and takes the user to the specified vendor from the dropdown menu -->
                <a href="<passed variable>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Order now!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And the following javascript that replaces the label of the dropdown-button:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));}
```

I want the "Ordner now"-button to be able to receive an external link to a vendor based on the dropdown menu. Meaning I would need to pass a variable to the button from the dropdown menu - So far I haven't managed to succeed in this.

I'm very new to both bootstrap and javascript and was hoping someone here might point me in the right direction as to how I should handle this.

I'm assuming I should be able to store an href-value with the items in the dropdown-menu and pass them on to the order-button when selected, but I've had no luck in trying to figure this out while at the same time not pointing the player directly to the vendor through the dropwdown-menu.

I've also experimented with forms without the desired effect. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but not sure as to what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the information for using bootstrap buttons here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/

I usually take the button and then wrap it in the  tag like this:

```
<a href="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Primary</button></a>
```

Notice how I made the button disabled by default, then you can use javascript/jquery to remove the disabled attribute when a certain action is performed on the page.

As far as setting it based on a different box being selected, you can also set the href="" attribute using jquery if you want it to live update without reloading the page, or if you're not worried about the page needing to be reloaded, you could use  inside the href quotes.

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks!

Didn't realise how easy this ended up being once I figured out that actually naming things makes things a whole lot easier.

Might not be the cleanest solution, but it works.

I'm enabling the button through the onclick-function of the dropdown-items and passing on the names of the items as href-links to the order button.